# From your experience, what are the top reasons that makes GIT hard to work with Salesforce?

Tags: git, github

I am inclined to know the most important issues of making GIT work with Salesforce.

Answer (score 1):

The biggest difficulty is that it is hard to fit it natually into your workflow. Ideally you would be developing in a version-controlled environment that you use to build your system.

In Salesforce, unless you are doing all of your development by manipulating xml configuration files (which is actually not such a bad option in some cases), your development efforts will be centered around changes being made in Salesforce where the build is essentially happening as you go. To use version control, all of those changes would need to be pulled out after the fact. What naturally tends to happen in my experience is that you only pull out those files when you are getting ready to do a deployment, and then, just saving the zip files that you are deploying provides a fairly good audit trail.

Also from the deployment perspective, removing something from the system requires you to explicitly state what you are removing in a destructiveChanges file. Re-deploying a prior version of your configurations won't necessarily return the system back to the state it was in the first time you deployed it. Even if you are retrieving all of the metadata for your org and managing it in one git repository, deploying a previous version back up to the system would not return it back to its former self.